# Make Pdo Preserve Backslash

Tags: php, pdo

Basically i want to store a path to an image into the database

Example:I want to save `'C:\wampp\www\project\images'` into database

Instead Pdo remove all the backslash and make it into `'C:wamppwwwprojectimages'`

Is there a way to make Pdo keep the backslash?

**Update with code:**

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO meal (pic_path) VALUES('C:\wamp\www\project')";
$db   = new PDO( $dsn, $username, $password );
$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Can you show us some code on how you are inserting and retrieving the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that this is happening is because you're using double quotes (`"`) around your query, and since the back slash (`\`) is the escape character, it's being dropped. You can fix this by placing two back slashes together so it will yield one (`C:\\wamp\\www\\project`).

However, Passing it to `prepare` as an argument would be a better idea, and you can keep the double quotes.

```
$directory = "C:\wamp\www\project";

$sql  = "INSERT INTO meal (pic_path) VALUES(?)";
$db   = new PDO( $dsn, $username, $password );
$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->execute(array($directory));
```

Read more [about prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1):

You should use PDO's variable substitution to safely insert values into the database. To edit your code, it would look like this:

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO meal (pic_path) VALUES(?)";
$db   = new PDO( $dsn, $username, $password );
$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->execute(array('C:\wamp\www\project'));
```

PDO will replace the ? in your query with the escaped version of the string you pass.